# JavaScript - losing array index after using "apply"

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
    // this is not looping through the "girls" array as expected, but breaking down
    // the first element of the array to its char elements
    
    var girls = ["sandy","katie","lynda","wendy"];
    
    function showGirlsTalent(girl) {
    
     for (var i in girl) {
      
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.talents.length + 1);
      console.log(girl[i] + ' can ' + this.talents[rand]);
     }
    }
    
    var talent = {
     
     talents:['dance','sing','act']
    }
    
    function createTalent(girl, callback) {
    
     showGirlsTalent.apply(callback,girl);
    }
    
    createTalent(girls, talent);
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `.apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply .

Comment: 1) You shouldn't loop through an array using `for..in`, 2) Your variable names are confusing; it is singular or plural? 3) Your "`callback`" is not really a callback, it's just an object; see 2)?

Comment: 4) You should be using `call`, not `apply` if you want the first argument to be your array

Comment: deceze, @Phil: why not post these comments as an answer?

Comment: @Nickolay because my answer would amount to *"RTFM"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [fun.apply(thisArg, argsArray)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) invocation, `argsArray = ["sandy","katie","lynda","wendy"]`, so you end up calling `showGirlsTalent("sandy","katie","lynda","wendy")`. You only use the first argument in `showGirlsTalent` and loop through it via `for..in` getting the individual characters.

You can figure this easily by using a debugger in your favorite browser. Do you know how to use it?